# Polymer observer is not fired

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, polymer

My code:

```
<google-youtube currenttime="{{videoTime}}" video-id="{{videoUrl}}"></google-youtube>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'youtube-video',

        properies: {
            videoUrl: String,
            videoTime: {
                type: Number,
                observer: 'timeChanged'
            }
        },

        timeChanged: function(){
            console.log('observer');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The element in the Polymer-Doc: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-youtube

> [image]

The `timeChanged` function is never called. Why?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The code looks good enough to me, have you tried to bind the currenttime to a span tag to see that it is actually working? I suspect the element might have a bug

Comment: Do you mean the `google-youtube` element?

Comment: Yes, I can see that the `google-youtube` element does not have any proper tests (for 1.0) written and the property `currenttime` is changed with `self.currenttime = value` instead of `this.set('currenttime', value)`. I therefore suspect a bug in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your `properties` declaration (missing a *t*), thus the observer is never registered. The `google-youtube` elements works fine and does update `currenttime` as expected.